# 2000AD comic from the 80s featuring a giant shark

Tags: story-identification, comics, 2000ad

This should be easy for someone to remember but I'm having no luck searching for it on the internet.

The UK comic 2000AD featured, very early on, a long running series about a giant shark and the people trying to hunt it. It ended on a very gruesome note

> with the main character being eaten by the shark

What was the name of that story series?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been through my 2000 AD collection up to issue 100, and I can't find any story matching your description. Are you sure you're not getting mixed up with a story about a great white shark called Hook Jaw that was published in a comic called [Action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_%28comics%29). If you Google this you'll find comments that it inspired the 2000 AD story about a polar bear called Shako.

Sadly I have never owned any copies of Action so I can't check whether the Hook Jaw story matches your description. [This site](http://www.sevenpennynightmare.co.uk/?p=110) reports it ends with a main character, Red McNally, being eaten by the shark.

Comment: That seems to be the one and I can't believe that there would have been two such stories around the same time. It was actually Rick Mason's death that I remembered.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be thinking of [Flesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesh_(comics)) - a 2000AD comic about people going back in time to hunt dinosaurs for meat? I recall that involving some prehistoric sharks or shark/crodilian dinosaurs.

Comment: GIven that the OP has already confirmed [the correct answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37948/2000ad-comic-from-the-80s-featuring-a-giant-shark#comment72184_37955), the answer to your question would appear to be "no".